# Sails.JS - проблема с созданием сессии

Tags: сессия, sails.js

Доброго дня.

Проблема возникла при изучении Sails.JS по sailsCasts (http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/)

При запуске приложения в лог выводится следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
verbose: A socket is being allowed to connect, but the session could not be loaded.  Will create an empty, one-time session to use for the life of the socket connection.  Details:
Error: Session could not be loaded
  at _createError (/home/feofanov/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:271:21)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/feofanov/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:274:13)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
 { [Error: Session could not be loaded] code: 'E_SESSION' }
...
verbose: Could not fetch session, since connecting socket has no cookie (is this a cross-origin socket?)
Generated a one-time-use cookie:sails.sid=s%3ArLsa3NEJesYaSpk2dgys0Y3UEAPISayv.xcswPCEfp3FOnIw%2FFk7s1NibIYhOl1CdJBF6IlK3P9Aand saved it on the socket handshake.
This will start this socket off with an empty session, i.e. (req.session === {})
That "anonymous" section will only last until the socket is disconnected unless you persist the session id in your database,
or by setting the set-cookie response header for an HTTP request that you *know* came from the same user (etc)
Alternatively, just make sure the socket sends a `cookie` header or query param when it initially connects.
```

Пытался подключать внешнее хранилище сессий (Redis) - не помогло.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    verbose: A socket is being allowed to connect, but the session could     not be loaded.  Will create an empty, one-time session to use for the life of the socket connection.  Details:
Error: Session could not be loaded
at _createError (/home/feofanov/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:271:21)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/feofanov/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:274:13)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
     { [Error: Session could not be loaded] code: 'E_SESSION' }
```

Ошибка возникает из за того что вы перезапустили сервер и сессия на сервере удалилсь, но вкладку в браузере вы не закрыли и на ней остался указатель на старую сессию которой больше не существует.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!